# `Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.`

Tags: android, database, cursor, android-room

I am using Room database along with RX observable in my app and encountering this error.

`Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException
Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.`

I have added the provided **@Transaction** annotation for my query but that doesn't have any impact. 
Since we don't have the direct access to the cursor so unable to do much on this . Can someone suggest me the solution for this?

Comment: are you storing any very large blobs in your table columns?

Comment: @pskink We just have data of actions we are doing  and have set a limit of 60 rows , in failed cases it might get increased.